# Regex to find words between two tags

Tags: python, regex

How can I use regex in python to find words between tags?

```
s = """<person>John</person>went to<location>London</location>"""
......
.......
print 'person of name:' John
print 'location:' London
```

Comment: Probably better to use an html/xml parser like BeautifulSoup

Comment: Between any tag or just the person and location tag?

Comment: see the famous http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `BeautifulSoup` for this HTML parsing.

```
input = """"<person>John</person>went to<location>London</location>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(input)
print soup.findAll("person")[0].renderContents()
print soup.findAll("location")[0].renderContents()
```

Also, it's not a good practice to use `str` as a variable name in python as `str()` means a different thing in python.

By the way, the regex can be:

```
import re
print re.findall("<person>(.*?)</person>", input, re.DOTALL)
print re.findall("<location>(.*?)</location>", input, re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: @Blender I don't know how to eliminate the tags. Can you help me?

Comment: `.string` is all you need. Also, `.find('person')` is equivalent to `.findAll('person')[0]`.

Comment: This won't find all text between any tag (of course, the question is unclear about this)

Comment: If you do not want to match the tags, use positive lookahead and lookbehind: `(?<=<person>)(.*?)(?=</person>)`

Answer (score 10):

```py
import re

# simple example
pattern = r"<person>(.*?)</person>"
string = "<person>My name is Jo</person>"
re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)

# multiline string example
string = "<person>My name is:\n Jo</person>"
re.findall(pattern, string, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

This example works for simple parsing only. Have a look at [python official documentation on `re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

To parse HTML, you should consider [@sabuj-hassan answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22248072/3323896) but please remember to check this [Stack Overflow gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) as well.

Comment: Does not work: `re.sub(br'<center>(.*?)</center>', b' ', b'<center>a\n</center>b', re.DOTALL)`

Comment: Well this is not exactly the code example I gave, but I suggest you replace `re.DOTALL` with `flags=re.DOTALL`. I just tried it and it still works. Hope that solve your problems :)

Answer (score 1):

```
probably you are looking for **XML tree and elements**
XML is an inherently hierarchical data format, and the most natural way to represent it is with a tree. ET has two classes for this purpose - ElementTree represents the whole XML document as a tree, and Element represents a single node in this tree. Interactions with the whole document (reading and writing to/from files) are usually done on the ElementTree level. Interactions with a single XML element and its sub-elements are done on the Element level.

19.7.1.2. Parsing XML
We’ll be using the following XML document as the sample data for this section:

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data>
```

We have a number of ways to import the data. Reading the file from disk:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('country_data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

Reading the data from a string:

```
root = ET.fromstring(country_data_as_string)
```

Other python Xml & Html parser

https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonXml
http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html