# Regular Expression match subtags in Python

Tags: python, regex, xml

I tried to develop a regular expression to match subtags.

I checked this post:
[Regex to find words between two tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247957/regex-to-find-words-between-two-tags)

This regular expreesion works to extract al values in "doc-number" tag.

```regex
*<doc-number>(.*?)</doc-number>
```

However, I want to get values that is inside another tag only. Let's we call . I tried the expression below, but it doesn't work.

```regex
"<patcit(.*?)<doc-number>(.*?)</doc-number>(.*?)</patcit>"
```

Can I get some help?

Sample XML file:

```xml
<us-citation>
<patcit num="00003">
<document-id>
<country>US</country>
<doc-number>6172888</doc-number>
<kind>B1</kind>
<name>Jochi</name>
<date>20010100</date>
</document-id>
</patcit>
<category>cited by examiner</category>
<classification-cpc-text>B23K 11/258</classification-cpc-text>
<classification-national><country>US</country><main-classification>363 89</main-classification></classification-national>
</us-citation>
```

Comment: What about using a XML parser instead?

Answer (score 1):

you [shouldn't be using regular expression to parse a XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/10009545). Instead [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) from the standard library is a better choice. Answers to the question ["How to use Xpath in Python"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692/how-to-use-xpath-in-python) might also be interesting.